# Multiply two arbitrary numbers in a string

Tags: c, string, math, arbitrary-precision

I have made the following code to perform multiplication between 2 arbitrary number stored in char * in C :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void    mult(char *n1, char *n2)
{
  char  *res;
  int   mul, i, j;

  res = malloc(sizeof(*res) * (strlen(n1) + strlen(n2) + 1));
  memset(res, '0', strlen(n1) + strlen(n2));
  res[strlen(n1) + strlen(n2)] = 0;
  for (i = strlen(n1) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
     for (j = strlen(n2) - 1; j >= 0; j--)
     {
        mul = (n1[i] - '0') * (n2[j] - '0');
        res[i + j] += ((res[i + j + 1] + mul - '0') / 10);
        res[i + j + 1] = ((res[i + j + 1] + mul - '0') % 10) + '0';
      }
    }
  printf("%s\n", res);
  free(res);
}
```

I compiled it with `-O3` flag but it takes about 30 seconds for big numbers with 86 k digits.
How I can make it faster?

Comment: First of all - why do you think it can be faster?

Comment: Try looking at the source code for `bc` and seeing if you can draw inspiration from that.

Comment: Because bc do it in ~2 seconds

Comment: Two nested loops imply O(n1 * n2) time complexity. First thing is to find out what is the best time complexity can be achieved theoretically.

Comment: Calling `strlen` once instead of multiple times in the inner loop could help somewhat,.

Comment: The `-'0'` can be eliminated by preprocessing the strings and substracting `-'0'` once from each character of the string.

Comment: Preprocessing the strings first (to make them digits) might help too.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Great minds think alike...

Comment: `i + j` could be computed once instead of multiple times, but maybe the compiler does this already for you.

Comment: Use bitshift for multiplication and division? (I think of dividing by ten and modulo ten)

Comment: @LotoLo the compiler most likely does this for you.

Comment: In pre-processing one could also group the digits by 4 and perform the multiplication in base 10000 using arrays of unsigned ints. Speedup by factor 16.

Comment: BUG: `mul - '0'` is wrong because the ASCII '0' was subtracted already.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: It is not a bug, since the reduction is for the array element, i.e., it should read `(res[i + j + 1] - '0') + mul`. But could be avoided via pre- and postprocessing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "help me improve my working code" questions belong on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Summing up comments:

- Try to avoid integer division. E.g. with lookup table. Product of two digits mean a maximum of 9^2. Use result of /10 or %10 for the other.
- Make sure the strlen() calls are stored, explicitly dedicate variables for them.
- Perform the +/-'0' trafo separately.
- Consider the base 10000 suggestion.

Perhaps using dedicated struct (dyn array + maintained size info) would be better than string. Length and the +/-'0' are performed only when I/O of numbers is neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

The following would then be a somewhat optimized version, using many of the comments' suggestions:

```
void mult(char *n1, char *n2)
{
  char  *res, *pres, *p1, *p2;
  int   mul, i, j, l1= strlen(n1), l2= strlen(n2);

  res = malloc(sizeof(*res) * (l1 + l2 + 1));
  memset(res, 0, l1 + l2);
  res[l1 + l2] = 0;

  for (i=0, p1=n1; i<l1; i++) *p1++ -= '0';
  for (j=0, p2=n2; j<l2; j++) *p2++ -= '0';

  p1= n1+l1-1;
  for (i= l1 - 1; i >= 0; i--, p1--)
  {
     p2= n2+l2-1;
     pres= res+i;
     for (j = l2 - 1; j >= 0; j--, p2--)
     {
        mul = *p1 * *p2;
        pres[j] += ((pres[j + 1] + mul) / 10);
        pres[j + 1] = ((pres[j + 1] + mul) % 10);
      }
    }
  for (i=0, p1=res; i<l1+l2; i++) *p1++ += '0';
  printf("%s\n", res);
  free(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid calling `strlen()` repeatedly. [@Michael Walz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407032/multiplicate-two-arbitrary-number-in-a-string-in-c#comment68064299_40407032) as `for (j = strlen(n2) ...` inside the `for (i ...` loop.
2. Rather than subtract/add `'0'` repeated, do it once at the beginning and end.  This is worthwhile for very long strings, less so for short ones.  [@Michael Walz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407032/multiplicate-two-arbitrary-number-in-a-string-in-c#comment68064437_40407032) [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh)
3. Rather than touch 2 product elements in the inner loop (once to add to  product, once for the carry), do so once and form a *carry*.
4. Take advantage of leading zeros.

Some untested code.  Be sure to free the free the returned pointer.  Coded for clarity vs. code-golfing.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void string_offset(char *s, size_t sz, int offset) {
  while (sz > 0) {
    sz--;
    s[sz] += offset;
  }
}

char * string_string_mult(char *a, char *b) {
  while (*a == '0') a++;
  size_t alen = strlen(a);
  size_t asz = alen + 1;
  string_offset(a, alen, -'0');

  while (*b == '0') b++;
  size_t blen = strlen(b);
  size_t bsz = blen + 1;
  if (a != b) {       // TBD to fully detect a,b, overlap
    string_offset(b, blen, -'0');
  }

  size_t psz = asz + bsz;
  char *product = calloc(psz, sizeof *product); // account for potential carry and \0
  if (product == NULL) return NULL;

  for (size_t ai = alen; ai > 0;) {
    ai--;
    char *p = product + ai + blen + 1;
    int acc = 0;
    for (size_t bi = blen; bi > 0;) {
      bi--;
      acc = *p + a[ai] * b[bi] + acc;
      *p = acc %= 10;
      p--;
      acc /= 10;
    }
    *p += acc;
  }
  string_offset(product, psz - 1, +'0');

  // test for an unneeded leading zero
  if (product[0] == '0' && (alen + blen > 0)) {
    memmove(product, product + 1, psz - 1);
  }

  string_offset(a, alen, +'0');
  if (a != b) {       // TBD to fully detect a,b, overlap
    string_offset(b, blen, +'0');
  }
  return product;
}
```

Details

- `a` and `b` may point to the same string.
- Memory allocation may fail.
- `size_t` is the best type to use for array indexing.
- The product may/may not form a final carry.

Answer (score 0):

I checked most of the suggested optimizations (except LutzL's base 10000 scheme which has promise) and they don't make a significant difference.  Since you've already identified `bc` as having the right stuff, why not simply use it instead of trying to reimplement it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

void mult(const char *n1, const char *n2) {
    FILE *pipe = popen("/usr/bin/bc", "r+");

    fprintf(pipe, "%s * %s\nquit\n", n1, n2);

    if (ferror(pipe)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Output to pipe failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE); // bc long lines are limited to 70 characters
    char *result = fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, pipe);

    while (result != NULL) {
        char *s = rindex(buffer, '\\'); // find and remove line continuation marker

        if (s != NULL) {
            *s = '\0';
        }

        fputs(buffer, stdout);

        result = fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, pipe);
    }

    (void) pclose(pipe);
}
```

On my system this multiplied two 86K digit numbers in under a second.

Note that my system (OSX) has bidirectional `popen()` which is unidirectional on many system so you'll need to use the recommended work around for your system for bidirectional communication.

The above code could use more error checking and you could play with the `bc` environment variable `BC_LINE_LENGTH` to generate longer lines for efficiency, and on some systems set it to zero to avoid line breaks.